Statistical test to find critical value where IV has effect on DV
Let's say I have an independent variable, that has an influence on a dependent variable, that is only really has an effect if a critical mass/quantity/value of the independent variable is reached.
For example number of hours trained, and performance on a test. Let's say there is a critical point, where training is only really effective, if you put more then 5 Hours into it, training for less than 5 hours has no significant effect, or a smaller effect. How would I test this exactly? I am thinking it could have something to do with creating dummy variables for each threshold, but is there a procedure for something like this?
